# Python requests close connection

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have a python request to capture the token number, after that I use this token to run another API url, afther that I want to close this current session, but I could not, like this:

```
url = 'https://10.10.20.21/tron/api/v1/tokens'
payload = {'grant_type': 'password', 'username': 'login', 'password': 'test@2021'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
```

If I print the text and headers, is possible to see:

```
print(f'text: {response.text}')
print(f'request.headers: {response.request.headers}')

text: "Maximum number of active sessions reached"
request.headers: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '57', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

So, I would like to close this current session/connection, but even when I run response.close() the connection still alive:

```
response.close()
```

My desire is to close this session in order to run another one.

Answer (score 2):

I've found myself in the same situation with ASUS Aura Rest API where after I don't know the lack of port numbers? Rest API server crashes.
Seems that despite that `request.Session` implementation I had to also add the header:
`{'Connection':'close'}` to the session
so now there are only pending connections visible with
`netstat -aon | findstr 27339`
Currently, which fixes the issue, the code looks like this:

````
def aura_command(self, command):
    aura_session = requests.Session()
    try:
        aura_session.verify = False
        aura_session.headers.update({'Connection':'close'})
        self.aura_connection(command, aura_session)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print('init_aura error')
    finally:
        print('closing session')
        aura_session.close()

def aura_connection(self, command, aura_session):
    if command == 'init':
        aura_session.post(self.aura_sdk_url, json=self.aura_init)
    elif command == 'stealth':
        aura_session.put(self.aura_sdk_url + '/AuraDevice', json=self.aura_stealth)
    elif command == 'intruder':
        aura_session.put(self.aura_sdk_url + '/AuraDevice', json=self.aura_intruder)
    elif command == 'windows':
        aura_session.put(self.aura_sdk_url + '/AuraDevice', json=self.aura_windows)
    elif command == 'deinit':
        aura_session.delete(self.aura_sdk_url, json=self.aura_init)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [`requests.Session`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) objects. They might give you the functionality you're looking for.

```py
from requests import Session

url = 'https://10.10.20.21/tron/api/v1/tokens'
payload = {'grant_type': 'password', 'username': 'login', 'password': 'test@2021'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

sess = Session()
sess.verify = False
sess.headers.update(headers)

response = sess.post(url, data=payload)

sess.close()
```

Comment: I looked into requests.Session but I could not find nothing to help me.

Comment: What exactly is happening in the rest of your code? I don't understand how you are saturating the number of open connections/sessions... Is the server you are contacting under your control? If so, is it multi-threaded (and how many concurrent requests can it handle)? Also, what is the reason you cannot re-use an already established connection/session?